# How to generate a random 4 digit number not starting with 0 and having unique digits?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, sampling

This works almost fine but the number starts with 0 sometimes:

```
import random
numbers = random.sample(range(10), 4)
print(''.join(map(str, numbers)))
```

I've found a lot of examples but none of them guarantee that the sequence won't start with `0`.

Comment: You can specify in `range()` the start value.In your case it could be 1

Comment: what do you mean by ***"having unique digits?"*** ? can you provide some samples?

Comment: @PedroLobito if you look at the existing code it should be obvious.

Comment: *This works almost fine but the number starts with 0 sometimes.*  Probably about 10% of the time, if you run it enough times.

Comment: For only four digits, Rejection is probably the best choice.

Comment: [Related PPCG challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/117506/34718)

Comment: A security related Q&A: [When choosing a numeric PIN, does it help or hurt to make each digit unique?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/155606/when-choosing-a-numeric-pin-does-it-help-or-hurt-to-make-each-digit-unique)

Comment: To the OP: Please retract your acceptance of your accepted answer. It should not be the accepted answer. It is the slowest of the top six answers, and by quite a wide margin.

Comment: @DavidHammen here's an even faster one: https://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: @Paul: It would have been funny if `4` were a correct output.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

We generate the first digit in the 1 - 9 range, then take the next 3 from the remaining digits:

```
import random

# We create a set of digits: {0, 1, .... 9}
digits = set(range(10))
# We generate a random integer, 1 <= first <= 9
first = random.randint(1, 9)
# We remove it from our set, then take a sample of
# 3 distinct elements from the remaining values
last_3 = random.sample(digits - {first}, 3)
print(str(first) + ''.join(map(str, last_3)))
```

The generated numbers are equiprobable, and we get a valid number in one step.

Comment: @Claudio Independence of the numbers generated is one of the fundamental properties a good  pseudo-random generator must satisfy. I suppose that Python's random is good enough that subsequent calls can be considered independent.

Comment: Note that, while this method does indeed generate each possible output with the same probability, this fact isn't trivially obvious. The key reason why it does produce equiprobable reasons is that, after picking the first digit, the number of remaining possible digits is the same regardless of which first digit was chosen. In particular, if you tried to reverse the procedure (i.e. first pick the lowest three distinct digits, and then pick a non-zero first digit out of the remaining seven), the outputs would *not* be equiprobable. (Exercise to readers: why?)

Comment: Downvoted because this is the slowest of the top answers. This combines set arithmetic with `random.sample`, both of which are slow.

Comment: @DavidHammen Why is that worthy of a downvote? On my machine, this answer is less than 4 microseconds slower than Austin Hastings answer, and performance wasn't even mentioned in the question. I would hesitate to call a constructive approach alongside rejection sampling techniques "not useful".

Comment: @Mitch - Mostly to counter what I consider to be completely invalid downvotes on the other answers due to lack of understanding of the concept of rejection sampling. An easy way to understand rejection sampling: Suppose I asked you to produce all of the four digit numbers that have no repeated digits and that start with 1. You could come up with a complex algorithm to do that, or you could use `[n for n in range(1000,10000) if len(set(str(n)))==4]`. (continued)

Comment: The `if` in the list comprehension that filters out values containing replicated digits is the equivalent of rejection sampling. Sometimes it's faster to intentionally generate invalid values and then filter them out. The exact same concept applies to rejection sampling.

Comment: I understand rejection sampling quite fine, thank you, and prefer Austin's answer to this answer as well. Downvoting a perfectly fine answer just seems... odd.

Answer (score 33):

Just loop until you have something you like:

```
import random

numbers = [0]
while numbers[0] == 0:
    numbers = random.sample(range(10), 4)

print(''.join(map(str, numbers)))
```

Comment: @Claudio the probabilities still work out to be equal for all results so I'm not sure what you mean by not as random as it should be

Comment: @Claudio I'm sorry but you should probably consult some kind of reference on accept-reject sampling and review conditional probability before suggesting all of the answers are incorrect.

Comment: This could loop forever. Hardly a versatile solution.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition, and all the other downvoters: This is a very versatile solution. It even has a name, "rejection sampling." Most implementations of a normal distribution use rejection sampling.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition, and all the other downvoters: Of the answers by Austin Hastings, MSeifert, karakfa, andThierry Lathuille, this is the fastest in both python 2.7 and python 3.4. In fact, the accepted answer is the slowest, 40% slower than is this answer (python 2.7).

Comment: @Mitch -- The probability of looping is even smaller than that. A call to `random.sample(range(10), 4)` will produce one of 5040 different lists, of which 504 have a leading zero. In other words, exactly one out of ten of the lists generated by that call to `random.sample` fails the criteria. The probability of having to loop at all is 10%, having to make two or more loops is 1%, four or more loops, 0.01%. The probability drops very quickly. The key problem with this approach is how poorly `random.sample` performs in python3.

Comment: @DavidHammen Ahh I thought he was using pure rejection sampling like MSeifert, didn't take a close look at the answer. You are correct.

Answer (score 20):

This is very similar to the other answers but instead of `sample` or `shuffle` you could draw a random integer in the range 1000-9999 until you get one that contains only unique digits:

```
import random

val = 0  # initial value - so the while loop is entered.
while len(set(str(val))) != 4:  # check if it's duplicate free
    val = random.randint(1000, 9999)

print(val)
```

As @Claudio pointed out in the comments the range actually only needs to be 1023 - 9876 because the values outside that range contain duplicate digits.

Generally `random.randint` will be much faster than `random.shuffle` or `random.choice` so even if it's more likely one needs to draw multiple times (as pointed out by @karakfa) it's up to 3 times faster than any `shuffle`, `choice` approach that also needs to `join` the single digits.

Comment: with this method, you need to reject more than half of the samples.  Target range: `9*9*8*7 = 4536`, sample space `8999`.

Comment: @karakfa But it avoids shuffling a "range" and joining the list and checking if the first item is 0. I think that's worth it. A superficial timing shows that this approach using `randint` is roughly 3 times faster compared to the `random.sample` approaches here.

Comment: @MSeifert Of course, that's for 4 digits. Your rejection space is going to blow up and slow you down with say, 7 digits (I know that's not the question :) ). Practically speaking though, I like this answer best.

Comment: Yes, it might be faster.  What I meant to comment is it's going to throw away more than half of the samples.  It might still very well be the most efficient one.

Comment: To make it even more perfect you can limit further the range for choices using for example **random.randint(1023, 9876)**, right?

Comment: I think I'd just put `val = 0` for the start. I don't like having to think about repeated digits that hard. +1, though.

Comment: While `random.randint` is much faster than is `random.sample`, `len(set(str(val)))` is very slow. The end result is that this is slower than Austin Hasting's algorithm in both python 2.7 and python 3.4, but not by much. This answer's algorithm is considerably faster than is that of the accepted answer, and because of that, +1.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition and MSeifert -- Fun fact: This algorithm can be sped up by over 10% by writing it as an infinite loop, with `val = random.randint(1023, 9876)` and ` if len(set(str(val))) == 4: break` as the body of the loop. This still uses the very expensive `len(set(str(val)))`, but does so one less time than does the code in the answer.

Comment: @DavidHammen You're right about the `break` being faster (however `randint` is slower than `len(set(str(val)))` so the difference wasn't that much. However I would be interested in how you did the benchmarks where my solution was slower, because I ran it on three machines and the results where roughly consistent: 2-4 times faster compared to the other 5 top-voted answers. So if you have any valid benchmarks proving me wrong I'll be happy to correct the answer :)

Comment: @DavidHammen Note that with python-3 the timings look very different: http://ideone.com/ous7zZ. Am I right that it seems my solution is a bit slower on python2 but much faster in python3?

Comment: @MSeifert - I didn't notice the python3 tag. I have experimented with both python2 and python3 and have noticed that performance is in general quite abysmal with python3. Your's is the one exception, being only 10% slower in python3 rather than python2 (other algorithms take twice as long, or longer). One thing that is common across both versions of the language is that the accepted answer is lousy.

Comment: @MSeifert -- Even your algorithm is a bit slower in python3 than it is in python2. I reduced the timeit `number` on ideone so as not to overly abuse their computers. Expand that number and it's clear than every algorithm is slower in python3. I suspect that python3 has drastically improved the performance of `len`, `set`, and `str`, but has somehow disimproved the performance of `random`, with particular attention paid to disimproving the performance of `random.sample` and `random.shuffle`.

Comment: @MSeifert - Wow. On my computer, `python -m timeit -s 'import random' 'random.sample(range(10),3)'` takes 2.41 usec per loop. With python3, it takes 6.38 usec per loop.

Comment: @DavidHammen Yeah, that was why I wrote that `randint` is much faster than `sample` (and `shuffle`). I'm not sure what changed, it could be that `range` doesn't return a list in python3 or that list indexing got slower but maybe they even fixed problems with the PRNG that resulted in slowdowns. But yeah, it's definetly interesting. Might be worth a follow-up question, we _probably_ can't solve this here in the comments. :)

Comment: On the other hand, `python -m timeit -s 'n=123345678' 'len(set(str(n)))'` takes 0.804 usec per loop with python, 0.74 usec per loop with python3.

Comment: Another problem we can't solve in comments: The accepted and most highly up-voted answer has incredibly lousy performance in both versions of the language. I don't understand the upvotes or the acceptance. This is a people problem rather than a language problem.

Comment: @DavidHammen Performance wasn't part of the question so I wouldn't judge on that point (even though it's good to point out). However the accepted answer doesn't need "sample rejection". Maybe that was the reason that made it the top-voted and accepted answer. :)

Comment: The (invalid) comments about rejecting the notion of rejection sampling were all about performance.

Comment: @MSeifert -- [Question asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43622101).

Comment: Nice answer. You might be interested in a [one-liner (after imports) variant of your code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43630843/6419007).

Answer (score 16):

I do not know Python well, but something like

```
digits=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] <- no zero
random.shuffle(digits)
first=digits[0] <- first digit, obviously will not be zero
digits[0]=0 <- used digit can not occur again, zero can
random.shuffle(digits)
lastthree=digits[0:3] <- last three digits, no repeats, can contain zero, thanks @Dubu
```

A more useful iteration, actually creating a number:

```
digits=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]   # no zero
random.shuffle(digits)
val=digits[0]                # value so far, not zero for sure
digits[0]=0                  # used digit can not occur again, zero becomes a valid pick
random.shuffle(digits)
for i in range(0,3):
  val=val*10+digits[i]       # update value with further digits
print(val)
```

After stealing pieces from other solutions, plus applying the tip from @DavidHammen:

```
val=random.randint(1,9)
digits=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
digits[val-1]=0
for i in random.sample(digits,3):
  val=val*10+i
print(val)
```

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, it's short and combinatorical.  It's exactly how I thought of doing it when reading the title.  Setting `first` to 0 after getting first digit is "clever", I would have just added zero back to the list.
This looks to be identical to Claudio's, which is tl;dr and less readable.
This can generate all 4536 answers, without unnecessary looping or testing.

Comment: This is good, except that it should read `lastthree=digits[0:3]` because of Python's unusual array indexing.

Comment: @toddkaufmann I wanted to do that first, just I did not know the syntax for appending an item, and then I realized it was not needed anyway

Comment: @tevemadar -- While correct, this is quite slow, with two calls to `random.shuffle` on a nine element list.

Comment: @DavidHammen I was not aware of other random functions, like random.sample (despite of using almost identical variable names, I have not spotted the later-accepted answer, there were much-much more failed answer attempts around). Adding a 3rd variant, by the way

Comment: @tevemadar - Much better. That puts you in fourth place on my computer, behind Austin Hastings, foo bar, MSeifert, but ahead of karakfa and Thierry Lathuille. So +1.

Comment: You mentioned that you don't know python well. One of the key things you need to unlearn is loop based on indices. Just loop over the thing you want to loop over. Do this and you will be on par with MSeifert's answer: Replace `tail=random.sample(digits,3)` and `for i in range(0,3): val=val*10+tail[i]` with `for n in random.sample(digits,3): val = val*10 + n`.

Comment: @DavidHammen Thank you, added the idea in the final code. If you have a strong stomach, please find a fast, but assembly-like approach in http://stackoverflow.com/a/43631936/7916438

Answer (score 11):

rejection sampling method.  Create a 4 digit random combination from 10 digits and resample if it doesn't match the criteria.

```
r4=0    
while r4 < 1000:
    r4=int(''.join(map(str,random.sample(range(10),4))))
```

noticed that this is essentially the same as @Austin Haskings's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43593479/1435869)

Comment: This could loop forever. Not useful.

Comment: Probability of that is zero...  You'll be surprised how common this technique is used in practice.

Comment: The probability is certainly _not_ zero.

Comment: `lim 10^(-n) = 0`; for `n -> Infinity` (aka forever)

Comment: Okay how about it could loop for two years. Is that more useful?

Comment: The probability is negligible for all practical purposes.  For example, to loop 1000 times without producing a valid sample (which takes 16 msecs on my computer) is probability 10^(-1000) event.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition - You are barking up the wrong tree here. Rejection sampling is a very widely used technique. The only problems with this answer is that Austin Hasking's wrote a very similar answer two minutes earlier (probably while karakfa was writing this answer) and that Austin Hasking's answer is a bit better.

Answer (score 11):

[Fixed] Shift all four digits on one position is not right. Swap leading zero with fixed position is not right too. But random swap of the leading zero with any of nine positions is correct and gives equal probability:

```
""" Solution: randomly shuffle all numbers. If 0 is on the 0th position,
              randomly swap it with any of nine positions in the list.

  Proof
    Lets count probability for 0 to be in position 7. It is equal to probability 1/10 
  after shuffle, plus probability to be randomly swapped in the 7th position if
  0 come to be on the 0th position: (1/10 * 1/9). In total: (1/10 + 1/10 * 1/9).
    Lets count probability for 3 to be in position 7. It is equal to probability 1/10
  after shuffle, minus probability to be randomly swapped in the 0th position (1/9)
  if 0 come to be on the 0th position (1/10) and if 3 come to be on the 7th position
  when 0 is on the 0th position (1/9). In total: (1/10 - 1/9 * 1/10 * 1/9).
    Total probability of all numbers [0-9] in position 7 is:
  9 * (1/10 - 1/9 * 1/10 * 1/9) + (1/10 + 1/10 * 1/9) = 1
    Continue to prove in the same way that total probability is equal to
  1 for all other positions.
    End of proof. """

import random
l = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
random.shuffle(l)
if l[0] == 0:
    pos = random.choice(range(1, len(l)))
    l[0], l[pos] = l[pos], l[0]
print(''.join(map(str, l[0:4])))
```

Comment: But the not every possible value is drawn with the same probability. Because for example `1234` and `01234` produce the same result while numbers containing a not-leading zero (e.g. `1023`) have only one possibility to be drawn.

Comment: @MSeifert Ahh you're correct.. How about swapping zero with a random location in the list should a zero-leading number be drawn? Then we redistribute evenly back across the sample space in that case.

Comment: e.g. `random.shuffle(l); if l[0] == 0: pos = random.choice(range(1, 10)); l[0], l[pos] = l[pos], l[0]`

Comment: @foobar No, MSeifert has a point. Your current approach doesn't draw from the sample space uniformly. (I think) my suggestion fixes this though.

Comment: @Mitch -- Yes, you're right. I'll fix my note according to your suggestion. And check it on [0,1,2] list with 2 unique digits not starting with 0. There are only 3! == 6 possibilities (easy to check).

Comment: @MSeifert -- Yes. For example, take list [0,1,2] and combine only two unique random digits not starting from zero. There are only 3! == 6 possibilities: [0,1,2]; [0,2,1];  [1,0,2]; [1,2,0];  [2,0,1]; [2,1,0]. If I shift on one position, I'll have [1,2] and [2,1] twice as often than [1,0] and [2,0]. So I should use suggestion of Mitch and **randomly** swap leading zero with the second or the third position. This will give the same probabilities.

Comment: I'm not really sure if that garantuees an even distribution. For example `1234` wouldn't hit the branch (say it would have a normalized probability of 1). But numbers like `1203` could be produced either by shuffling once (probability 1) and by drawing `0213` (granted it's a chance of 1/9th). Thus these would have a probability of `~1.1`. This reasoning may be wrong (I'm not a statistician) and I personally liked the original approach (it was very simple and therefore elegant!). Even distribution wasn't part of the question so a skewed distribution would answer the question just fine.

Comment: @MSeifert -- Lets take simpler example: list [0,1,2] and two unique digits not starting with 0. There are 3!==6 possibilities. Each possibility has probability 1/6. There are 2 leading zeros: [0,1,2] and [0,2,1]. If **randomly** swap leading 0 with the rest 2 positions, there are four combinations: [0,1,2]==>([1,0,2] and [2,1,0]); [0,2,1]==>([2,0,1] and [1,2,0]). Each of these four combinations have the same probability equal to 1/6 * 1/2 == 1/12. But these 4 combinations coincide with the rest 4 possibilities. So each possibility after random swap should have probability == 1/6 + 1/12.

Comment: Yes, you're totally right. :) I forgot that `02341` could also produce `1234`. I'm glad I did not remove my upvote based on my flawed argument. (even though I **really** liked your first approach). :)

Comment: @MSeifert -- added mathematical proof.

Answer (score 7):

You could use full range for 3 numbers, then choose the leading number among the remaining numbers:

```
import random
numbers = random.sample(range(0,10), 3)
first_number = random.choice(list(set(range(1,10))-set(numbers)))
print(''.join(map(str, [first_number]+numbers)))
```

Another way if the choice needs to be repeated (and if you remain reasonable on the number of digits), is to pre-compute the list of the possible outputs using `itertools.permutations`, filtering out the ones with a leading zero, and building a list of integers from it:

```
import itertools,random

l = [int(''.join(map(str,x))) for x in itertools.permutations(range(10),4) if x[0]]
```

That's some computation time, but after than you can call:

```
random.choice(l)
```

as many times you want. It's very fast and provides an evenly distributed random.

Comment: Except the allowable outcomes aren't equally likely then; e.g., there are two ways to get 1230, but only one way to get 1234.

Comment: @TimPeters you're right. Added an alternate solution.

Comment: if you get 0023, then you have the same problem

Comment: but you cannot have `0023`. There's only one `0`

Answer (score 4):

I don't know Python so I will post a pseudo-code-ish solution for this specific problem:

- Create a lookup variable containing a 0-based list of digits:

  ```
  lu = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
  ```
- Generate four 0-based random numbers as follows:

  ```
  r1 = random number between 0 and 8
  r2 = random number between 0 and 8
  r3 = random number between 0 and 7
  r4 = random number between 0 and 6
  ```
- Use the lookup variable to convert random numbers to digits one-by-one. After each lookup, mutate the lookup variable by removing the digit that has been used:

  ```
  d1 = lu[r1]
  lu.remove(d1)
  lu.insert(0)

  d2 = lu[r2]
  lu.remove(d2)

  d3 = lu[r3]
  lu.remove(d3)

  d4 = lu[r4]
  lu.remove(d4)
  ```
- Print the result:

  ```
  print concatenate(d1, d2, d3, d4)
  ```

It is possible to generalize this idea a little. For example you can create a function that accepts a list (of digits) and a number (desired length of result); the function will return the number and mutate the list by removing used-up digits. Below is a JavaScript implementation of this solution:

```js
function randomCombination(list, length) {
    var i, rand, result = "";
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
        result += list[rand];
        list.splice(rand, 1);
    }
    return result;
}

function desiredNumber() {
    var list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        result;
    result = randomCombination(list, 1);
    list.push(0);
    result += randomCombination(list, 3);
    return result;
}

var i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(desiredNumber());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd do it

```
while True:
    n = random.randrange(1000, 10000)
    if len(set(str(n))) == 4: # unique digits
        return n
```

More generally, given a generator, you can use the built-ins [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) and [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to take the first element that satisfies some test function.

```
numbers = iter(lambda: random.randrange(1000, 10000), None) # infinite generator
test = lambda n: len(set(str(n))) == 4
return next(filter(test, numbers))
```

Comment: `return` outside a function is a syntaxerror in python. Also note that you can use a range from `1023` to `9876` as pointed out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43593278/how-to-generate-a-random-4-digit-number-not-starting-with-0-and-having-unique-di/43613235#comment74241467_43593794).

Answer (score 1):

## Combine generators with `next`

A Pythonic way to write would be to use 2 nested generators and `next`:

```
from random import randint
from itertools import count

print(next(i for i in (randint(1023, 9876) for _ in count()) if len(set(str(i))) == 4))
# 8756
```

It's basically a one-liner variant of [@MSeifert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43593278/how-to-generate-a-random-4-digit-number-not-starting-with-0-and-having-unique-di/43593794#43593794)

## Preprocess all the acceptable numbers

If you need many random numbers, you could invest some time and memory for preprocessing all the acceptable numbers:

```
import random    
possible_numbers = [i for i in range(1023, 9877) if len(set(str(i))) == 4]
```

`1023` and `9877` are used as boundaries because no int lower than 1023 or greater than 9876 can have 4 unique, distince numbers.

Then, you'd just need [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) for a very fast generation:

```
print(random.choice(possible_numbers))
# 7234
```

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: this is a terrible anti-Python approach, strictly for the benchmarking part (see @DavidHammen's comments around, and http://ideone.com/qyopLF)
The idea is to generate the sequence numbers of the digits in one step, and then fix any collisions:

```
rnd=random.randint(0,4535)
(rnd,d1)=divmod(rnd,9)
(rnd,d2)=divmod(rnd,9)
#(rnd,d3)=divmod(rnd,8)
#(rnd,d4)=divmod(rnd,7)
(d4,d3)=divmod(rnd,8) # miracle found: 1 divmod happens to run faster than 2
```

Now we have d1=0..8, d2=0..8, d3=0..7, d4=0..6, it can be tested via running the snippet with rnd=4535 (4535=9*9*8*7-1, by the way)

First, d1 has to be patched up

```
d1=d1+1 # now d1 = 1..9
```

Then d2 has to "skip" d1 if necessary

```
if d2>=d1
  d2=d2+1 # now d2 = 0..9 "-" d1
```

Then the same has to be done with the remaining digits, getting ugly fast:

```
if d3>=d1:
  d3=d3+1    # now d3 = 0..8 "-" d1
  if d3>=d2:
    d3=d3+1  # now d3 = 0..9 "-" {d1,d2}
elif d3>=d2: # this branch prepares for the other variant
  d3=d3+1
  if d3>=d1: # ">=" is preserved for consistency, here "==" may occur only
    d3=d3+1
```

And the final part is the catastrophic one:

```
if d4>=d1:
  d4=d4+1
  if d4>=d2:
    d4=d4+1
    if d4>=d3:
      d4=d4+1
  elif d4>=d3:
    d4=d4+1
    if d4>=d2:
      d4=d4+1
elif d4>=d2:
  d4=d4+1
  if d4>=d1:
    d4=d4+1
    if d4>=d3:
      d4=d4+1
  elif d4>=d3:
    d4=d4+1
    if d4>=d1:
      d4=d4+1
elif d4>=d3:
  d4=d4+1
  if d4>=d2:
    d4=d4+1
    if d4>=d1:
      d4=d4+1
  elif d4>=d1:
    d4=d4+1
    if d4>=d2:
      d4=d4+1
```

For longer numbers, it might work faster with bitfields, but I do not see a trivial way.
(Checking the >= relations once is not enough, because the collision can easily occur after doing an incrementation.
e.g. d1=1, d2=2, d3=1: d3 collides with d1, but it does not collide with d2 initially. However after "puching the hole" at 1, d3 becomes 2 and now it collides with d2. There is no trivial way to spot this collision in advance)

As the code stinks as hell, I put a verification step at the end

```
val = d1*1000 + d2*100 + d3*10 + d4
#if len(set(str(val))) != 4: print(str(val)+" "+str(o1)+","+str(o2)+","+str(o3)+","+str(o4))
if len(set(str(val))) != 4: print(val)
```

It is already faster than the other really fast code (the commented verification displayed the original digits preserved after the divmod-s, for debugging purposes. This is not the kind of code which works immediately...). Commenting both verifications makes it even faster.

EDIT: about checking this and that

This is an approach maintaining an 1:1 relation between the minimal set of valid inputs (0...4535) and valid outputs (the 9*9*8*7 possible 4-digit numbers with distinct digits, not-starting-with-0). So a simple loop can and should generate all the numbers, they can be checked one-by-one and they can be collected into a set for example in order to see if they are all distinct results

Practically:

```
collect=set()
for rnd in range(0,4536):
    (rnd,d1)=divmod(rnd,9)
    ... rest of the code, also the verification step kept active ...
    collect.add(val)
print(len(collect))
```

1) It will not print anything in the loop (all results are 4-digit numbers with distinct digits)

2) It will print 4536 at the end (all results are distinct)

One can add a verification for the first digit (d1), here and now I just assume that
"(something mod 9)+1" will not be 0.

Comment: Interesting. Did you check that the results are uniformly distributed?

Comment: @EricDuminil the distribution over the set of valid outputs follows the distribution of randint(). What I checked is the correctness of mapping inputs to outputs, added some lines about it now

Answer (score -6):

This will allow zeros after the first digit -

```
numbers = random.sample(range(1,10),1) + random.sample(range(10),3)
```

Comment: It will also allow a single repeated digit.

Comment: Would you need to multiply the first digit by 1000 before adding the two? Or does the plus sign just concatenate them?